# Magento 2.4 fails to install due to missing composer config file in composer_home

Tags: magento2

I tried to install Magento 2.4 via command line. It runs smooth until

```
[Progress: 653 / 1206]
Module 'Magento_ComposerRootUpdatePlugin':
```

At this step the installation fails with

```
Installing data... Reading /<magento_root>/composer.json
Loading config file /<magento_root>/composer.json
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /<magento_root>/var/composer_home/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Composer is installed globally. The Magento documentation does not mention anything else regarding composer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Facing the Same Error Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /Users/mac/sites/ewlicense/var/composer_home/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section I also tried composer self-update but it still not fixed the issue. the Url is giving me 502 Bag Gateway

Comment: I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: @hardy123480 Were you able to install Magento 2.4.0 even if it's shown this error?

Comment: Kind of. What I now tried is to install a local instance of composer in the Magnet root directory. It still throws the error but the installation goes through successfully. Unfortunately, I get 502 Bad Gateway if I want to access the frontend / backend. I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @hardy123480 which php version are you running? 7.4.8?

Comment: Yes, 7.4 but also tried 7.2

Comment: @hardy123480 but exactly 7.4.8? 7.2 should be not supported. Magento 2.4.0 supports ˜7.3 and ˜7.4. It has been tested on 7.4

Comment: Not exactly sure at the moment. Maybe it was 7.3. Did you get it running?

Comment: @hardy123480 I'm trying but no success till now. Which OS are you using?

Comment: @hardy123480 are you using MySql or MariaDB? Which version?

Comment: @hardy123480 just tried using php 7.3.20 but same result.

Comment: I'm also taking a look at composer root update plugin issue: https://github.com/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/issues/15

Comment: It seems the same bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28673

Comment: Did you find out any solutions? You can follow my question here if you want: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319278/magento-2-4-0-fails-to-install

Answer (score 11):

Here's a workaround - after creating the project from magento Repo, create the composer.json file

```
cd var
mkdir composer_home
cd composer_home
vim composer.json
```

composer.json contents-

```
{
}
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: has you installed custom modules via composer in vendor source path  ? and installed or register in magento ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. But it was solved by creating auth.json in var/composer_home like this

```
{
   "http-basic": {
      "repo.magento.com": {
         "username": "your username key",
         "password": "your password key"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you it works

Answer (score 0):

@Gabriela

it works for me...but command prompt says

**"Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/var/composer_home/composer.json"**

should i create composer.json instead of auth.json and add your mentioned code.

also please mention, which username and password should i add.

many thanks,
rakshith

Answer (score 0):

Installed 2.4 ok but got this same error running setup:upgrade. 2.4.x requires composer v2.

Run `composer self-update --2` from appropriate account and issue should go away. If you get permission denied and can't elevate then your hosting company will need to do this.