# Magento2 suggestion on which version to be used

Tags: magento2

- The latest version of magento is 2.4.0 & it is compatible with PWA studio version 7.0.0. But going with Magento2 latest version issue will be extension that we purchase might not be compatible with latest version of Magento.
- On the other hand if we go with 2.3.4 then we need to use downgraded version of studio 6.0.0

Can some one suggest which version I should go with?

Comment: If you have option to choose extension vendors, try to go with ones that do regular updates and that are present on magento marketplace, that can help with picking the one that will get update that covers latest magento version releases

Comment: I'm on the fence too since 2.4.0 is a really big change over 2.3.x version but 2.4.0 seems to be buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always start with the latest stable version and always upgrade to the latest stable version as you go.
This is valid for any software not just Magento.
Why?

- The latest version contains the latest security fixes, the latest bug fixes.
- Previous versions will not be supported for long after a new version appears.
- most probably, the newest version has the newest features.

You should not worry about some extensions not being compatible with the latest version.
Usually the big extension vendors make their extensions compatible with the latest version because, well, that's their source of money.

Comment: Yeah, usually it should. But Magento 2.4.0 is full of bugs. You can even install it using composer as described.

Comment: @KaMZaTa, Not sure what you mean. I successfully installed it.

Comment: Using composer? Fresh install or upgrade?

Comment: fresh install. I did not attempt an upgrade yet.

Comment: Might I ask you how you did by answer here ( https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318915/magento-2-4-fails-to-install-due-to-missing-composer-config-file-in-composer-hom ) or here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248003/how-to-resolve-magento-2-2-4-version-localhost-500-server-error-during-install ) or here ( https://www.reddit.com/r/Magento/comments/i3dli5/magento_24_fails_to_install_due_to_missing/ )? What's your environment? Thanks