# Magento 2.4.0 fails to install

Tags: installation, magento2.4

**I'm trying to make a fresh install of Magento 2.4.0**. I want to say in advance I didn't have any problem at all in installing Magento 2.3.5 with PHP 7.3.20. Anyway...

---

Here's my config:

- Debian 10
- Apache 2.4.38
- PHP 7.4.8
- MariaDB 10.4.13
- Composer 1.10.10

---

## The installation process

1. I tried either method: by uploading all files directly and by using Composer:

   ```
   composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition magento
   ```
2. After that, I set the permissions:

   ```
   chmod 775 -R /var/www/magento && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magento && cd /var/www/magento && find . var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc app/code app/design -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc app/code app/design -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chown -R :www-data . && chmod u+x bin/magento
   ```
3. Then I run the installation command:

   ```
   magento setup:install --base-url=https://dev.example.com --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=mypassoword --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=myuser@gmail.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=mypassword --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=Europe/Rome --use-rewrites=1
   ```

   and I received some errors:

   ```
   Module 'Magento_ComposerRootUpdatePlugin':
   Installing data... Reading /<magento_root>/composer.json
   Loading config file /<magento_root>/composer.json
   Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /<magento_root>/var/composer_home/composer.json
   To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
   ```
4. Then I tried to reach the frontend and I got this error:

   ```
   An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.
   ```

   And this is the var/log/exception.log

   ```
   main.CRITICAL: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor does not exist at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26)"} []
   ```

---

#### What I tried

- I tried to recompile, flush the cache, deploy...
- I replaced MariaDB 10.4.13 with Mysql 8.0.21...

Any ideas?

Comment: your forth options error your run step wise commands like :- first of **`var/cache var/view_preprocessed , compile , setup:upgrade, deploy and cache , and last flush`** commands and try again

Comment: run this command : sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/

Comment: @MohitPatel `rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* && magento c:f && magento setup:upgrade && magento setup:di:compile && magento indexer:reindex && magento cache:disable full_page translate layout block_html && magento c:f` then it throws a HTTP 500 Error.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Done, then it throws a HTTP 500 Error.

Comment: I think permission issue apply permission and check

Comment: Do you know if permissions are changed from 2.3.5 to 2.4.0?

Comment: @MohitPatel `chmod 775 -R /var/www/magento && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/magento && cd /var/www/magento && find . var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc app/code app/design -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc app/code app/design -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chown -R :www-data . && chmod u+x bin/magento`. Is that right?

Comment: @MohitPatel I always run that command on past Magento version and it worked great.

Comment: @MohitPatel just executed as `magento_user` the following `cd /var/www/magento && sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && chown -R :www-data . && chmod u+x bin/magento` (as written in the docs) before running the installation command but nothing's changed. Then I tried anyway with no success a `setup:upgrade, compile, etc...`

Comment: @MohitPatel it doesn't work even if I set 777 permissions on the whole Magento folder...

Comment: check your log error

Comment: @MohitPatel there are only 4 files in `var/log/` : `cron.log` which shows just `main.INFO...`, `magento.cron.log` which is empty, `debug.log` which shows some `main.INFO...` and `main.WARNING...`, and `system.log` which shows a `main.INFO...`.

Comment: @MohitPatel of course, there is the `var/log/exception.log` as well as described up above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, with no little effort, I found out **Magento 2.4.0 raised issues with my Nginx reverse proxy** set in front of Apache and Varnish (until Magento 2.3.5-p2 it worked fine).

In order to solve this I had to increase the proxy buffer in this way ([here some reference](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx)):

```
server {

    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://192.168.1.100;

        ...

        proxy_buffers              128 8k;
        proxy_buffer_size          512k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    512k;
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put an empty JSON object into your global config.

```
echo "{}" > ~/.composer/composer.json
```

Next run all commands like upgrade, di,static-content, cache flush, permission

(OR) add public key and private key in the composer.  you will get keys from magento account.

Comment: Thanks but why should I add an empty JSON object into the user composer global config (that, by the way, it doesn't exist)? What's the purpose? Furthermore, why should I also add the Magento credentials in the composer file? Anyway, as I wrote, the problem persists even uploading all files directly thus without using composer method.

Comment: i got same issue so i have added composer so problem solved for me. some dependence modules install using with keys

Comment: Done but it didn't work. Since I'm using Debian I had to create `~/.config/composer/composer.json` and add `{}` as you wrote. I also tried to add the Magento credentials but nothing's changed.

Comment: How should I add public and private key in `var/composer_home/composer.json` file? Can you provide an example?