# Fresh Magento 2.4, nginx reverse Proxy can't redirect to fresh Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4

I am installing a fresh Magento 2.4 on a docker-compose stack with these specs:

1. Reverse proxy: jwilder/nginx-proxy

```
 ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy
```

2. web running apache expose on port 80 and 22.

Long story short, I have had no problem installing magento 2.3.5 and before that with that docker-compose setup.  But starting Magento 2.4.0, I added elasticsearch container to my setup, confirm seeing setup landing page "Welcome to Magento Admin".  But after i run /bin/magento setup:install with Basic install. I am getting "502 Bad Gateway".  I suspect my reverse proxy can't detect my web container apache after running setup:install but it was able to see it before running setup:install.   So what change to my apache.conf file I need to setup to get thing work again.  What could go wrong here.  I can't think of any.  Any help?

Thanks

Comment: did you have any luck with this? I have the same issue...

Comment: Please see this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319278/magento-2-4-0-fails-to-install

I fixed it but can't remember exactly steps I took.  Long story short, I still stick around with 2.3.6 because some of my modules are not compatible with 2.4.1

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go!