# Cloud installation detected error message while running bin/magento-docker ece-deploy

Tags: magento2-cloud, magento-2-commerce, cloud-docker

I'm having a hard time setting up my local Magento cloud environment. I'm following this guide:

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-development.html

The exact steps I'm taking are:

1. Cloning the magento-cloud project: `git clone https://github.com/magento/magento-cloud.git`.
2. Adding my enterprise credentials to the `auth.json` file using `composer config`.
3. Running `composer update`.
4. Running this command to create the docker-compose file with xdebug and mutagen file sync (on Linux): `vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose --mode="developer" --with-xdebug --set-docker-host --sync-engine="mutagen"`
5. Running `docker-compose up -d` and then `docker-compose run --rm deploy cloud-deploy`

After that, I got the error:

```
Installing data... Reading /<magento_root>/composer.json
Loading config file /<magento_root>/composer.json
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /<magento_root>/var/composer_home/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section.
```

So I created an empty `composer.json` file in `/var/composer_home` following the advice in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/319488/97879). That solved that issue, but now I'm getting this:

```
Loading config file /app/composer.json
Loading config file /app/auth.json
Reading /app/auth.json
Reading /app/var/composer_home/composer.json
Loading config file /app/var/composer_home/composer.json
Reading /app/vendor/composer/installed.json
Reading /app/composer.lock
Checking for "magento/composer-root-update-plugin: 1.1.2" for the Web Setup Wizard...
Cloud installation detected, not installing magento/composer-root-update-plugin for the Web Setup Wizard
Reading /app/composer.json
Loading config file /app/composer.json
Loading config file /app/auth.json
Reading /app/auth.json
Reading /app/var/composer_home/composer.json
Loading config file /app/var/composer_home/composer.json
Reading /app/vendor/composer/installed.json
Reading /app/composer.lock
Checking for "magento/composer-root-update-plugin: 1.1.2" for the Web Setup Wizard...
Cloud installation detected, not installing magento/composer-root-update-plugin for the Web Setup Wizard
```

I've tried running `bin/magento-docker ece-deploy` instead of `````docker-compose run --rm deploy cloud-deploy```, but that didn't help. I also deleted everything and started from scratch just in case I missed something but had the same result.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Removing the magento/composer-root-update-plugin dependency allowed me to complete the deployment, but probably that's not the right way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround - after creating the project from Magento Repo, create the composer.json file

cd var

mkdir composer_home

cd composer_home

vim composer.json

composer.json contents

{

}

Hope this works for you.

Comment: That's not the problem. The issue is after I do that.